# How to update Google Cloud Datastore on a given Time or Interval?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, telegram-bot

I'm writing a `Bot` for `Telegram` using `Python` ([Using this as a Base](https://github.com/yukuku/telebot)) and `Google App Engine`.

I created a `Datastore` where I store how often a User has send something in a Chat and I update a Counter to prevent spam by saying `If Counter > x don't answer`.

```
class SpamFilterDB(ndb.Model):
    UserID = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    ChatID = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    Counter = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

Some example data:

[image: Some Example Data]

Now I want to decrease the Counter for all Users by x at some defined time (e.g. ever day) again to allow Users to use the Bot again.

How to do that?

Note: I would say my Python skills are still on a beginner level.

Comment: Can you add your code? What did you try?

Comment: @jezrael I added some Code hope that helps and I didn't really tried something because I didn't know where to start.

Comment: Can you try to read it? http://www.reddit.com/r/Telegram/comments/3b1pwl/create_your_own_telegram_bot_stepbystep/

Comment: @jezrael yes everything is working as I want it to be mainly I want to have a  function that runs at a specific time everyday or any other solution that would help with that problem

Comment: look at apengine cron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a [scheduled task](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron?hl=en) that will query a special URL in your application on a given schedule. In your handler for the URL, you can decrease the counter.

Comment: That looks like what I was looking for and I tried that now I have the question how to write the handler that goes through all entities and decreases the Counter

Comment: Which part of that task is presenting a difficulty for you?

Comment: I thought of a loop that goes through every entity and change the Count but I don't know how to set that loop up

Comment: You just had a perfectly good loop in your comment. Why did you remove it?

Comment: It was formatted a bit weird ^^
[Here is a Picture from the Code](http://i.imgur.com/aWbRVFl.png)
But that gives me this Error `in get for entry in qry.get(): TypeError: SpamFilterDB' object is not iterable`

But at least it gives me the error every Minute which is the loop I set in corn^^

Comment: You don't need the `.get`(). Try simply `for entry in qry`